# Why doesn't Firefox/Chromium see my usb camera?

Tags: webcam, browser, camera

When I try to join a video conference through Firefox or Chromium the browser I can select my usb camera (Logitech c930e) as an available microphone but doesn't list as an available camera. When I use another application like Cheese the camera works fine.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 on x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

The camera shows up with devices /dev/video2 and /dev/video3. Both have no world permissions and only have permissions for owner (root) and the group video. Adding my user to the video group fixed the problem:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER
```

That doesn't explain why Cheese worked fine, but both browsers now see the camera and offer it as an option.

Comment: Chromium is a snap app, just wondering if you have firefox as snap app also, instead deb app?  Snaps are known to have problems opening/using USB connected devices

Comment: @crip659 No not -problems-. It is the whole idea/concept of sandboxing.

Comment: Adding the user to the video group worked for me too on Ubuntu 22.04. Think it needed a reboot not just a log out.